# How do you enumerate the names and types inside a struct or class at compile time in D?

Tags: reflection, d, compile-time

How do you enumerate the names and types inside a struct or class at compile time?

i.e. to do the following:

```
struct Foo {
  int x;
  int y;
}

string serialise!(A)(A a) {
  ...magic...
}

auto f = Foo(1,2);
serialise(f); -> "x:1, y:2"
```

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Do you really need this enumeration in _compile_ time? Because from code I see that Reflection can do what you need.

Comment: @Iaroslav could you point me to an example of how reflection can be used in D?

Comment: Yes, it would be more (runtime) efficient to generate the serialisation functions at compile time.

Comment: sorry, I misread the tag. My bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
foreach (index, field; myStruct.tupleof)
{
    // field.stringof is "field", slice is to cut off "myStruct."
    pragma(msg, "Name: " ~ myStruct.tupleof[index].stringof[9..$]);
    pragma(msg, "Type: " ~ typeof(field).stringof);
}
```

Practical example: https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/master/utils/json.d#L107